# Socket Programming multiple client one server on windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, serversocket

Is it possible to have multiple client with socket programming on windows phone? I want to found number of connected client too.

I found `StreamSocketListener` there is no method for number of client, and I think it's support one client only.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Rohit I want to create a game over wifi and the games need 4 player ( 4 windows phone 8 device )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, You can create this. Try using realtimeframework.messaging library.You can get it from [here.](https://github.com/realtime-framework/Messaging) It supports most of platforms. You need application key, authentication token and private key which can be obtained from their website. It's very easy to use and reliable.

Comment: I want use socket through local network without internet

Comment: Yes you can do that. You just need a local server which act as reflector and sends all messages to devices on same channel